# How to check if conda and pip install in the same directory?

Tags: pip, conda

I want to make sure both commands install packages in the same folder. How to check that

> 'pip install'
>
> 'conda install'

both put new packages, libs in same directory?

Comment: I'm not sure how, but why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Ben, to not have to deal with libs that depend on each other installed in diff folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conda install -p [PATH] #will allow you to override the default path it is installed in`

`pip show [package name] #will show you where a package is installed`

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/